# Why do I get in my timespec-array the error "array type has incomplete element type"?

Tags: c

I got a problem with my C-Code in Eclipse. To be specific my sleep-method does produce an error in the line where the timespec is stated. May you guys can tell me what I did wrong? Here's the code:

```
void sleep(double time) {
    nanosleep(
        (struct timespec[]) { {time,((time -((time_t)time)) * 1000000000)}},
        NULL);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to include the header file which defines the *type* `timespec`. Either:

- You forgot to include the header file or
- You merely forward declared the type.

Second seems the most likely cause of error. Since you are creating an array, the compiler needs to know the definition of `timespec` as it needs to allocate that much memory for the array.

---

The problem is that `struct timespec` and `nanosleep()` are not defined in the C standard. They are provided by POSIX standard. It seems you are compiling with `-std=c99` or so which makes your compiler to strictly adhere to the C99 standard and hence report errors. To be able to compile these POSIX constructs you will have to explicitly enable them.

**[Compilation with `std=c99`](http://ideone.com/rdYnGh)**

**[Compilation after enabling POSIX definitions](http://ideone.com/w9XGQ5)**:

```
#if __STDC_VERSION__ >= 199901L
# define _XOPEN_SOURCE 600
#else
# define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500
#endif /* __STDC_VERSION__ */

#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    double time = 0.1;

    nanosleep((struct timespec[]) { {time, ((time - ((time_t)time)) *
               1000000000)}}, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

`__STDC_VERSION__` checks if the compiler you are using is c99 & depending on the compiler it enables the POSIX definitions.
`_XOPEN_SOURCE` defines which version of POSIX you want to refer to. Select the definition as per the POSIX version you use. `600` refers to `POSIX 2004` while `500` refers to `POSIX 1995`.

Comment: mhhh....ok.....is it possible you show me a short example so that I understand what do you mean?

Comment: @user1993028: Where is `struct timespec` defined? (possibly)in some header. Have you included that header file in your source(`.c`) file.I am putting it in as easy words as possible, it can't get any simpler than that.If you are trying to learn c through a forum its a bad idea.You need a [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to learn.Forums are to ask questions when you are stuck with specific problems(*coincidently you have in this case*),

Comment: @user1993028: We can help you with your specific problem but you need to understand the language atleast enough to decipher what we suggest you.

Comment: My struct timespec is nowhere defined, because normally it could be used in the nanosleep function as far as I known from the websites. However my header looks like this: `#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#ifdef TEST
 #define runLoop for(int i=0; i<=9; i++)
#else
 #define runLoop while(true)
#endif`

Comment: Yes I'm trying to call nanosleep but what I want to do is to let this operations be done. However I'm stuck into it because when I build the workspace I got the error "array type has incomplete element type" as I wrote in the subject

Comment: @WolfgangPansi: Updated the answer with the root cause and the solution.Hth.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Yes I've forgot to tell that I'm using -std=c99 and now everything is working fine.

Comment: @WolfgangPansi: Good for you :)

Comment: The new standard C11 has in fact `struct timespec` and a function called `thrd_sleep` that has the same interface and semantics as POSIX' `nanosleep`.

Comment: `struct timespec` is defined in [`<time.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/time.h.html#tag_13_76) when you are working with POSIX definitions enabled, as you would discover if you looked at the definition of [`nanosleep()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/nanosleep.html).  Note that you are treading on very thin ice by redefining [`sleep()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sleep.html) which is declared by `<unistd.h>`.  Choose a different name for your `sleep()` function (`double_sleep()`, perhaps, or `dsleep()`?).